# Very strange behaviour jQuery load() with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I really can't work out what's going on here. I'm using the jQuery load() method to replace some HTML within a page. In this case it is to replace the current message with one selected from a list by the user.
It's all working as expected except for one vital thing. When the HTML is returned it has added the word "ARRAY" before anything else. There is no other info (like you would get from var_dump()) and no tags. Literally, just the word in capital letters! If I load the view without using AJAX then it renders as expected. The only difference is that the request was made with AJAX. Here's the relevant code:

js: (all wrapped in ready())

```
$('.message_summary').click(function() {
        // get message id
        id = $(this).attr('id');

        // load the new message first so that user can get on with reading it
        $('#message_window').load($.baseurl+'messages/get_message/'+id);

        // mark as read
        $.get($.baseurl+'messages/ajax/mark_as_read/'+id);

        // get current tag id
        $.get($.baseurl+'messages/get_current_tag', 
            function(data){
                            // get the message count
                            $.get($.baseurl+'messages/ajax/set_new_message_count/'+data,
                                    function(msg_count)
                                    { 
                                        $('.new_message_count_'+data).html(msg_count);
                                    }
                                );
            });           
});
```

CI controller:

```
 public function get_message($message_id=false)
    {
        if($message_id)
        {               
            // get an individual message and prepare for display
            $message = $this->messages_m->get_single_message($message_id);

            foreach($this->tags['id'] as $index => $tag)
            { 
                $tag_options[$tag] = $this->tags['tag_name'][$index];
            }


            $main_message = array(
                                    'message_id'    => $message_id,
                                    'tag_name'      => $message->tag_name,
                                    'tag_options'   => $tag_options,
                                    'sender' => $message->first_name.' '.$message->last_name,
                                    'date_received' => date($this->config->item('date_time_format'), $message->created_at),
                                    'subject' => $message->subject,
                                    'content' => $message->message
                                );                                    
            if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
            {
                return $this->load->view('partials/message_view', $main_message);
            }
            else
            {
                return $this->load->view('partials/message_view', $main_message, true);
            }
        }
```

The view file is just HTML with some php variables.

Anyone got any ideas?!?!

Comment: I haven't use CI before, but I've use other PHP MVC frameworks. Is there perhaps a main template in use for the ajax view rendering that contains the word `ARRAY`. Alternativly, you could search through your project (most editors/IDE's have this ability) and search for the capitalised word `ARRAY`

Comment: What have you tried in terms of debugging? For example, what happens when you `exit('Something')` as the first line? I can't see any explanation for this based on only what you posted, and would be pleasantly surprised if anyone else can.

Comment: Thanks @devmatt for the suggestion, but I don't think that's the problem. Firstly, I've done a search of the whole project and nothing came up. Secondly, when the view is loaded from AJAX it doesn't go through any kind of templating. When the page is first loaded the same view is loaded with no problems, it only goes wrong when loaded by AJAX.

Comment: @Wesley Murch, I've been at a bit of a loss as to how to debug! I've used Firebug to check the exact response from the AJAX call. I can't see anything strange except that it includes "ARRAY" as part of the response. I've tried using var_dump but that didn't yield anything. I'm not sure exactly what you mean with your exit('Something') suggestion - could you elaborate?

Comment: OK, put this as the first line of `get_message()`: `if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) exit('Hello');` and tell us what you get.

Comment: oh yeah, dumb - sorry. So I get Arrayhello

Comment: @Wesley Murch Thank you so much!! I found the problem a few levels in a global(ish) controller's construct(). All sorted now having moved the offending lines! Could you write your suuggestions as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: @musoNic80: I was a step ahead of you there! I added some extra tip about ajax detection, glad you got it sorted out. GL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to try to help you debug in an answer instead of buried in comments.

We've tried `if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) exit('Hello');` as the first line of `get_message()` and the output was `Arrayhello`. This leads me to believe that somewhere, you are checking for an AJAX request and `echo`ing some array, as this is what will happen if you try to do that.

**My first advice**: Go back to your `__construct()` in the same Controller and do the same thing. If you still get the same result, go back even further, perhaps to a library that is being used. If you *don't* see `Array` anymore, start using the exit code a little further down the road until you find a point where it seems to trigger. FYI since you said you are new to the concept of debugging code, this is not ***the*** way to debug, it is just one way.

Also, it seems from your comment you get `Array` instead of the uppercase version now? That's weird, it doesn't sound right. Make sure you are reading the actual response in Firebug instead of what is visible on screen in your page.

**Aside**: A little convenience tip (something I do): Set `$this->input->is_ajax_request()` as a constant like `IS_XHR` or `AJAX` somewhere like in your index, constants file, or config. It just makes it easier to work with. Will the request change from ajax to non-ajax in one request? No. Just check out the source code for it in `system/core/Input.php`, it's extremely simple. Example:

```
define('AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

This is literally what the Input class does, although it's a little obfuscated. Now you can just use:

```
 if (AJAX) do_ajax_stuff();
```

Just a personal preference, but I find it very helpful - and it's slightly less resources being used.